# Angular 2 with .NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, angular

I am trying to integrate Angular into existing .NET MVC project. I have not made any changes in default `route.config` file because if I make changes as :

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

To...

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{*anything}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The above does not work either and return error as
"*No route in the route table matches the supplied values*"

Adding the required folder structure, config files, and other required files results in "*Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:51822/Home/systemjs-angular-loader.js*"

But I already have the `systemjs-angular-loader.js` in the project folder, `views->shared` and `views->home` folders.
Please let me know what changes I can do to make it work.

Comment: In what page do you want to use angular? If it is login page, than it's very bad practice

Comment: try adding `<base href="/">` to your layout.cshtml file. It is giving 404 error as `systemjs-angular-loader.js` is not present at path http://localhost:51822/Home/systemjs-angular-loader.js

Comment: Adding <base href="/"> to layout.cshtml helps .. and resolves the issue Thanks Ajinkya